# Pseudo element overlaps child element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

[Fiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/Chrisstar56/ty3a15wn/3/)

```css
 .wrapper {
   justify-content: center;
   display: flex;
   background: black;
 }
 .outer {
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   background: #555;
 }
 .outer::before {
   display: block;
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 5px;
   background: orange;
   transition: all 0.3s;
 }
 .outer:hover::before {
   height: 100%;
 }
 .inner {
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="outer" href="#">
    <span class="inner">
            Hover
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

you look at the fiddle and hover over the box, you'll see that the ::before pseudo element overlaps the text. I researched for half an hour but didnt find an answer. I'd appreciate if you can give me some help on how I can make the element dont overlop the text.
I can use data attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `position: relative` to the CSS rules for `.inner`.

```css
.wrapper {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background: black;
}
.outer {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #555;
}
.outer::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: orange;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.outer:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="outer" href="#">
    <span class="inner">
        Hover
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I believe what's happening is that the `position: absolute` on `.outer::before` is putting it in a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), and `span.inner` is stuck in another stacking context below. Adding `position: relative` to `.inner` brings your text into a whole new stacking context above everything else.

I also forked your Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/unitof/LqLd00wp/).

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @JacobFord perfect. Nice work, upvote comin' right up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the pseudo element transition to a larger size, transition the background color of the element to match the pseudo element. It gives the a similar effect.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidhartman00/yvk9u2fh/7/)

```
.wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    background: black;
}
.outer {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.outer::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: orange;
}
.outer:hover {
    height: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I didn't spend very long on this so maybe it can be tweaked to match your effect as originally intended.